# Создать DataFrame по алгориту

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Мне необходимо создать DataFrame по алгоритму.
Задаваться будет только количество столбцов
Необходимо сделать, чтоб в каждом столбце были данные от 1 до 99
Пример
Массив из 3-х:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
....
1 1 99
1 2 1
1 2 2
...
1 99 99
2 1 1
...
99 99 99
```

в идеале начальное и конечное число (1 и 99) тоже задать как переменные

Подскажите быстрый способ это сделать.
(у меня задача примерно из 10 столбиков. Если делать без dataframe то 3 столбика создаются около 7 секунд, 4 столбика уже 7 минут, а 10 столбиков - наверное не дождусь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать быстро кортеж через генератор с помощью itertools, и его уже в DataFrame втянуть.

```
import itertools
from pandas import DataFrame

ids = 1
ide = 100
col = 3
gen = (x for x in itertools.product(*[range(ids, ide + 1) for f in range(col)]))
dfr = DataFrame(tuple(next(gen) for _ in range(ide ** col)))
```

С точки зрения экономии памяти можно, к примеру, записать на диск данные, которые потом прочитать через read_csv()

```
import itertools
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv

ids = 1
ide = 100
col = 4
gen = (x for x in itertools.product(*[range(ids, ide + 1) for f in range(col)]))

with open('t.csv', 'w') as file:
    for _ in range((ide) ** col):
        file.write('{}\n'.format(','.join(str(r) for r in next(gen))))

dfr = read_csv('t.txt', header=None)
```

На диске 1.2 Гб, в памяти 3.6 Гб у процесса

*Добавлено по комментарию:*

На примере варианта 1 меняем параметр `ids` (id start) на 2, плюс в `range(ids, ide + 1, step)` в генераторе добавлен параметр шага

```
import itertools
from pandas import DataFrame

ids = 10
ide = 90
step = 2
col = 3
gen = (x for x in itertools.product(*[range(ids, ide + 1, step) for f in range(col)]))
dfr = DataFrame(tuple(next(gen) for _ in range(((ide - ids) // step + 1) ** col)))
```

Comment: Способ красивый, но к сожалению на 4 столбика машина съела всю оперативку и 30 ГБ файл подкачки.

Comment: @Sergei тогда можно списки поменять на кортежи (см. поправленный код). С памятью должно быть лучше, но все-равно много займет. Кортеж меньше занимает места, чем список, но вот объект датафрейма будет точно больше.

Comment: я вот тоже думаю уже, что надо сохранить результаты в файл, чтоб не пересчитывать потом.
Спасибо, пошел пробовать.

Comment: А как изменить код для того,чтоб данные начинались не с 1 а с другого задаваемого числа, и шаг делать произвольный?

Comment: @Sergei добавил в ответ код. В функции `range()` в итераторе выставляем начало, конец и шаг `range(start, end, step)`. Или нужен шаг виде функции от номера итерации `step(id)`?

Comment: В примере последнем массив останавливается раньше необходимого например если только 2 столбика то он считает: (если от 1 до 100 с шагом 2) 95 1...99 97 1 и все, а должен еще пройти 97 1...99 и 99 1...99

Comment: @Sergei поменял строчку `dfr = DataFrame(tuple(next(gen) for _ in range(((ide - ids)// step)** col)))` на `dfr = DataFrame(tuple(next(gen) for _ in range(((ide - ids + 1)// step)** col)))`. Небольшая ошибка в вычислении размера массива.

Comment: Все равно раньше времени остановился
сделал 3 столбика, шаг 2 от 10 до 90
получаю последний ряд
86  14  88

Comment: Все, нашел. Не туда плюсовал единицу `dfr = DataFrame(tuple(next(gen) for _ in range(((ide - ids) // step + 1) ** col)))`

Comment: спасибо, работает корректно. Буду подбирать значения, которые сможет ПК посчитать

Answer (score 0):

Задача пока не имеет практического решения в настоящее время, т.к. количество элементов в Вашей таблице будет равно 100 в степени 100 и умноженное на 100, на что не хватит оперативной памяти. Если это высоко научный проект, можно попробовать вместо оперативной памяти воспользоваться физической памятью, что, скорее всего, займет очень много времени. Человеческая жизнь от рождения длиться 2 млрд. секунд. Рекомендую сопоставить трудозатраты с ценностью проекта.